# C: realloc works on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, algorithm, sorting

this is my first question on Stack Overflow, sorry if it's not well written.
I have a little problem. I wrote a program in C (I'm currently learning C, I am a newbie, my first language, don't say I should've learnt Python, please, because I'm doing just fine with C). So, I wrote this little program. It's an attempt of mine to implement a sorting algorithm (I made the algorithm myself, with no help or documentation, it's very inefficient I think, I was just fooling around, though I don't know whether the algorithm already exists or not). The only sorting algorithm I know is QuickSort.
In any case, here is the final program (has plenty of comments, to help me remember how it works if I'll ever revisit it):

```
// trying to implement my own sorting algorithm
// it works the following way:
// for an array of n integers, find the largest number,
// take it out of the array by deleting it, store it
// at the very end of the sorted array.
// Repeat until the original array is empty.
// If you need the original array, simply
// make a copy of it before sorting
/***************************************/
// second implementation
// same sorting algorithm
// main difference: the program automatically
// computes the number of numbers the user enters

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int *sort(int *a, int n);                         // sort: the actual sorting function
char *read_line(char *str,int *num_of_chars);     // read_line: reads input in string form
int *create_array(char *str, int n);              // create_array: counts the num of integers entered and extracts them
                                                  // from the string the read_line function returns, forming an array
int size_of_array_to_be_sorted = 0;               // of integers

int main(void)
{
  int *array, i, *sorted_array, size = 3;
  char *str = malloc(size + 1);

  if (str == NULL)
  {
    printf("\nERROR: malloc failed for str.\nTerminating.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Enter the numbers to be sorted: ");
  str = read_line(str, &size);

  array = create_array(str, size + 1);
  sorted_array = sort(array, size_of_array_to_be_sorted);

  printf("Sorted: ");
  for (i = 0; i < size_of_array_to_be_sorted; i++)
    printf("%d ", sorted_array[i]);
  printf("\n\n");

  return 0;
}

int *sort(int *a, int n)
{
  int i, j, *p, *sorted_array, current_max;

  sorted_array = malloc(n * (sizeof(int)));
  if (sorted_array == NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR: malloc failed in sort function.\nTerminating.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)      // repeat algorithm n times
  {
    current_max = a[0];             // intiliaze current_max with the first number in the array
    p = a;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)         // find the largest integer int the array
      if (current_max < a[j])
      {
        current_max = a[j];
        p = (a + j);                // make p point to the largest value found
      }
    *p = INT_MIN;                        // delete the largest value from the array
    sorted_array[i] = current_max;       // store the largest value at the end of the sorted_array
  }

  return sorted_array;
}

char *read_line(char *str, int *num_of_chars)
{
  int i = 0;     // num of chars initially
  char ch, *str1 = str;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    str1[i++] = ch;
    if (i == *num_of_chars)                             // gives str the possibility to
    {                                                   // dinamically increase size if needed
       str1 = realloc(str, (*num_of_chars)++);
       if (str1 == NULL)
       {
         printf("\nERROR: realloc failed in read_line.\nTerminating.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
     }
  }
  // at the end of the loop, str1 will contain the whole line
  // of input, except for the new-line char. '\n' will be stored in ch
  str1[i++] = ch;
  str1[i] = '\0';  // store the null char at the end of the string

  return str1;
}

int *create_array(char *str, int n)
{
  int *array, i, j, k, num_of_ints = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)                         // computing number of numbers entered
    if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n')
      num_of_ints++;

  array = calloc((size_t) num_of_ints, sizeof(int));    // allocacting necessary space for the array
  if (array == NULL)
  {
    printf("\nERROR: calloc failed in create_array.\nTerminating.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  k = 0;
  i = 1;                          // populating the array
  for (j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)
  {
    switch (str[j])
    {
      case '0': case '1': case '2':
      case '3': case '4': case '5':
      case '6': case '7': case '8':
      case '9': array[k] += ((str[j] - '0') * i);
                i *= 10;
                break;
      case '-': array[k] = -array[k];     // added to support negative integers
      default:  i = 1;
                if (str[j] == ' ' && (str[j - 1] >= '0' && str[j - 1] <= '9'))
                     /* only increment k
                      *right before a new integer
                      */
                  k++;
                break;
    }                                                                      
  }
  // the loop works in this way:
  // it reads the str string from the end
  // if it finds a digit, it will try to extract it from the
  // string and store in array, by adding to one of the elements
  // of array the current char - ASCII for '0', so that it actually gets a digit,
  // times the position of that digit in the number,
  // constructing the number in base 10: units have 1, decimals 10, hundreds 100, and so on
  // when it finds a char that's not a digit, it must be a space, so it resets i
  // and increments k, to construct a new number in the next element of array

  size_of_array_to_be_sorted = num_of_ints;
  return array;
}
```

I've written everything myself, so if you think I use some bad methods or naive approaches or something, please tell me, in order for me to be able to correct them. Anyways, my problem is that I have these 'try to handle errors' if statements, after every call of malloc, calloc or realloc. I have a Linux machine and a Windows one. I wrote the program on the Linux one, which has 4GB of RAM. I wrote it, compiled with gcc, had to change a few things in order to make it work, and it runs flawlessly. I have no problem. I then copied it onto a USB drive and compiled it with mingw on my Windows machine, which has 8GB of RAM. I run it, and if I give it more than 3 2-digit integers, it displays 
ERROR: realloc failed in read_line.
Terminating.
At least I know that the 'error handling' if statements work, but why does this happen? It's the same code, the machine has twice as much RAM, with most of it free, and it runs with no problem on Linux.
Does this mean that my code is not portable?
Is it something I don't do right? 
Is the algorithm wrong?
Is the program very, very inefficient?
Sorry for the long question. 
Thanks if you wanna answer it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the amount of RAM and everything to do with undefined behavior. Have you stepped through your `read_line` function with a debugger and watched the values of your variables? Have you tried a tool such as `valgrind`?

Comment: Can you show the input that produced the error?

Comment: `valgrind` will tell you that `read_line` is writing one byte past the end of the allocated buffer as soon as you reach the 4th character of any input. (+1 for including an MCVE)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't know how to use valgrind. I've heard of it before though.

Comment: Maybe I should've just used a library function like gets or fgets, instead of trying to write my own function. But I learn C from C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition, by K. N. King, and when the author talked about strings, he said that the C functions for strings aren't that good all the time, so we might want to write our own functions for handling strings.

Comment: For a starter: **never ever** use `gets`!

Comment: when calling `realloc()`,  always save the returned pointer into a temporary pointer variable,  Then check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  Only if successful then copy the pointer to the target pointer.  This is because if the call to `realloc()` failes and the code immediately sets the target pointer then the original pointer is not recoverable, resulting in a memory leak and if the code tries to use that pointer when the call to `realloc()` failes, then will be trying to access memory near address 0 which will result in a seg fault event

Comment: the code exits without cleaning up after it self I.E/ expecting the OS to cleanup after sloppy code.  This is a very poor programming practice and should be avoided.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) variable names should indicate usage or content (or better both).  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default)  via a blank line 4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines

Comment: these two lines: `str1[i++] = ch;
  str1[i] = '\0'; ` are not checked to assure that there is room in the malloc'd input buffer, so can write past the end of the input buffer.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: this line: `str1 = realloc(str, (*num_of_chars)++);` is passing the original size of the input buffer to `realloc()`, so the allocated buffer will not be expanded.  Then after the call to `realloc()`, then the num_of_chars is being incremented by one.  But that is too late

Comment: error messages should be output to stderr, not stdout.  and it is a good idea when the error was from a return code from a system function to also output the associated text with that error.  Suggest to use `perror( "your error message" );` rather than `printf()`

Comment: this line: `case '-': array[k] = -array[k];` should be followed by a `break;` statement

Comment: the `create_array()` function does not properly handle malformed input, like an extra `-` character.  If the first char is a `-`, do NOT immediately multiply by -1 rather, set a flag, then at the end of the input, for that integer, if the flag is set then perform the multiply by -1 and reset the flag.  probably should only allow a `-` as the first character in an integer

Comment: what do you expect to happen if the user entered:`123abc456-`?

Answer (score 4):

The line in question is:

```
str1 = realloc(str, (*num_of_chars)++);
```

where `*num_of_chars` is the current size of `str`.  Because you are using *post-increment*, the value passed for the new allocation is the same as the current one, so you haven't made `str` any bigger, but go ahead and act as if you had.

Comment: So should I use pre-increment? I did realize this when I wrote the program, but didn't give it too much attention.

Comment: @Matthew: it would be better to write something like `str1 = realloc( str, *num_of_chars + N );` and only update `*num_of_chars` *after* you verify the `realloc` call succeeded.  Note that it's generally more efficient to `realloc` in larger chunks, rather than one byte at a time.